# Can't locate a hidden private page

Tags: pages, admin, private

I have 9 published page, and 1 private (invisible) page, in total 10 pages. However, my wordpress says that there are (2) private page, and total of (11) pages. How can I locate the unseen page??

FYI, I log in to my wordpress CMS as Admin user, and tried to log in to other user account, however, I can't see the hidden page at all... I want to delete it...as it's very annoying... Does anyone has a similar problem?

I've attached a screenshot here, and as you can see, I'm currently in the Private tab, and it shows only one page available, while it says that there's suppose to be (2) private pages..... >.<

[image: screenshot of my wordpress private page tab]

P/S: I've modified the tile due to confidential issue.

Comment: Have you tried to find it directly in DB?